# fullscreen image does not work angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using this [directive](https://github.com/hrajchert/angular-screenfull) I found. I want that if I click on an image, it goes on fullscreen, but this is not happening. I don't have errors in my console, and `ng-touch` is installed.

here is my code:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="cityController">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-33" ngsf-fullscreen>
            <img ngsf-toggle-fullscreen src="img/images/opera.jpg">
        </div>




angular.module('starter.cityController', ['ionic', 'angularScreenfull'])
.controller('cityController', function ($scope){

});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Refer this - https://github.com/hrajchert/angular-screenfull  . 
Have you included the css?
.fullscreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: I did. but it is not working

Comment: Have you included the javascripts? 
 <script src="bower_components/screenfull/dist/screenfull.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-screenfull/dist/angular-screenfull.min.js"></script>

Comment: I did till the beginning.